# Python MySQLdb placeholders syntax

Tags: python, mysql, pylons

I'd like to use placeholders as seen in this example:

```
cursor.execute ("""
    UPDATE animal SET name = %s
    WHERE name = %s
    """, ("snake", "turtle"))
```

Except I'd like to have the query be its own variable as I need to insert a query into multiple databases, as in:

```
query = """UPDATE animal SET name = %s
           WHERE name = %s
           """, ("snake", "turtle"))
cursor.execute(query)
cursor2.execute(query)
cursor3.execute(query)
```

What would be the proper syntax for doing something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
query = """UPDATE animal SET name = %s
           WHERE name = %s
           """
values = ("snake", "turtle")

cursor.execute(query, values)
cursor2.execute(query, values)
```

or if you want group them together...

```
arglist = [query, values]
cursor.execute(*arglist)
cursor2.execute(*arglist)
```

but it's probably more readable to do it the first way.