# How can I use python's function in mysql command?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm currently trying to connect to mysql, and I could connect to mysql-server using MySQLdb library, but I have no idea how can I put my functions inside the mysql command.
So, my function is named "accountname" and here is my current code.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO id(id, name) VALUES (accountname, hahaha)")
```

Database name:DB
Table name:id

 if you have any question, just ask me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python MySQLdb placeholders syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527941/python-mysqldb-placeholders-syntax)

Comment: yay!I could do that by using + variable + thing.

Comment: Be aware that using just "+" will make you possibly vulnerable to an SQL injection attack - use placeholders!