# How to correctly use mysql connector placeholders %S in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I am trying to read and write to a mysql database using python3 and mysql.connector. However I am having issues when using the "%s" placeholder in my synthax. Consider the following code:

```
import mysql.connector

dbconfig = {"host": "xxxxx",
            "user": "xxxx",
            "password": "xxxx",
            "database": "test"}

connection = mysql.connector.connect(**dbconfig)
cursor = connection.cursor()

_SQL ="""
SELECT surname, %s, %s FROM home;
"""

cursor.execute(_SQL, ("familyname", "hungry",))
response = cursor.fetchall()
for element in response:
    print(element)
```

test/home is a database/table of animals in our household I created just to play around with this. It has an id, surname, familyname and a value for how hungry they are. The code is supposed to basically display every entry in the table, but I tried to specify the rows to select by using the "%s" placeholder.

However this leads to some strange results. If my SQL looks like this:

```
_SQL ="""
SELECT %s, %s, %s FROM home;
"""
cursor.execute(_SQL, ("surname","familyname", "hungry",))
```

I get a result like this:

```
surname, familyname, hungry
surname, familyname, hungry
surname, familyname, hungry
surname, familyname, hungry
```

If I mix my code up a little like this:

```
_SQL ="""
SELECT surname, %s, %s FROM home;
"""
cursor.execute(_SQL, ("familyname", "hungry",))
```

I get:

```
moor, familyname, hungry
boris, familyname, hungry
whiskey, familyname, hungry
sherry, familyname, hungry
```

I played around with this trying to debugg, but to no avail. The only thing I realised is, that "%s" does not allow me to be used instead of the table name. Other than that it should be fine. However, it seems like hardcoded column names work as intented, but when used with "%s" something is going wrong.

I have found this topic:
[Python MySQLdb placeholders syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527941/python-mysqldb-placeholders-syntax)

Another user had issues with those placeholders and a working code example I found was:

```
query = """UPDATE animal SET name = %s
           WHERE name = %s
           """
values = ("snake", "turtle")

cursor.execute(query, values)
```

Except for the tuple of names being wrapped up in another variable (values) I dont see how the placeholder is used any different in here

So I wonder what is the correct way to use those query placeholders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%s` or `%(name)s` parameter style are used to format **values**.

So this line of code:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT %s FROM foo', ("bar",))
```

Is giving this query:

```
SELECT "bar" FROM foo
```

Which returns "bar" as expected. But what you want is:

```
SELECT bar FROM foo
```

In the first query `"bar"` is interpreted as a value to return, where `bar` is interpreted as the column to fetch.

But this code:

```
cursor.execute('UPDATE tablename SET foo=%s WHERE bar=%s', ('foo', 'bar'))
```

Gives this query:

```
UPDATE tablename SET foo='foo' WHERE bar='bar'
```

Here, having `'foo'` and `'bar'` as string makes sense since it's the values you want to update.

Answer (score 1):

These placeholders are intended to be used for values (upon execution).

If you want to change the query (change the fields, etc...), you should do some string manipulation.

Take a look at this for an idea:

```
fields = ("familyname", "hungry",)

_SQL = f"""
SELECT surname, {', '.join(fields)} FROM home;
"""

print(_SQL)

cursor.execute(_SQL)
```